# Toggle groups based on a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, toggle

I have a reporting requirement in which I have 3 groupings
Group_1 parents -> Group_4 lowest child

I have a groupingID param which is an int that I'm using to show the same report either as region/div or emp/supervisor. Group_1 =totals and Group_4 = Employee and NULL for region/division.

Updated requirements want me to not show toggle button at Group_3 = Region level if GroupingID is set to region/division. As region is the lowest level.
While still show toggle "+" button if grooupingID param is emp/supervisor.

I tried this expression for "row visibility but to no luck.
=iif(Parameters!GroupingID.Value=1,True,iif(Fields!Group_4.Value=Nothing,True,False))

This expression shows + for Reg/division report.

Comment: i have it working to the point with properties of Group_3 and Group_4 via properties window have following expressions set for [Visibility]
[Hidden] = =iif(Parameters!GroupingID.Value=1,True,False)
[Toggle State] = =iif(Parameters!GroupingID.Value=1,True,False)

Now only thing left is if there is a way to removed "+" completely for Region/Division level report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Architect proposed a solution which solved it. Add a new column in tablix to the left of all the groupings.
Depending on which group level you wish to toggle (in my case at group_3) just use the text box (to the left) of group_3 text box as 'toggle item by' in the properties for group_4. This solved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Row visibility is more for whether or not you want to show a particular row.  When I've had a need to show a summary and detail, I would make 2 tablixes and show/hide the proper one based on my parameters.

I'm not sure if you can conditionally change grouping sets via row level expressions, but if you could, it would probably be a lot more ugly than doing separate tablixes.  Down side to this approach is that you have 2+ tablixes that are similar to maintain.